# Could not find the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in ""

Tags: qt, compilation, pyside

I made a simple "hello world" with Qt Designer and I compiled it with auto-py-to-exe. No error message during compilation but when I double click on the created executable then I have this in my terminal:

```
(venv) (base) saltz@saltz:~/Bureau/70 5 applications Qt/test/output$ ./main
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. 
Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Abandon (core dumped)
```

I tried this after my research on the internet

```
root@saltz:/home/saltz/Bureau/70 5 applications Qt/test/output# export 
QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1
root@saltz:/home/saltz/Bureau/70 5 applications Qt/test/output# ./main
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/saltz/Bureau/70 5 
applications Qt/test/output/platforms" ...
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. 
Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Abandon (core dumped)
root@saltz:/home/saltz/Bureau/70 5 applications Qt/test/output# ln -sf 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/ /usr/bin/
root@saltz:/home/saltz/Bureau/70 5 applications Qt/test/output# ./main
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/saltz/Bureau/70 5 
applications Qt/test/output/platforms" ...
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. 
Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Abandon (core dumped)
root@saltz:/home/saltz/Bureau/70 5 applications Qt/test/output#
```

and this

```
base) saltz@saltz:~/Bureau/70 5 applications Qt/test/output$ cd /usr/lib/x86_64- 
linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms
(base) saltz@saltz:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms$ ldd libqxcb.so
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffda8389000)
libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 (0x00007ff6a38e6000)
libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007ff6a32f6000)
libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007ff6a2da6000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ff6a2bbe000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff6a29c6000)
libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 
(0x00007ff6a297e000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007ff6a28be000)
libQt5DBus.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5 (0x00007ff6a281e000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff6a27f6000)
libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007ff6a27ee000)
libxcb-xinput.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-xinput.so.0 
(0x00007ff6a27c6000)
libxcb-icccm.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-icccm.so.4 (0x00007ff6a27be000)
libxcb-image.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-image.so.0 (0x00007ff6a25b6000)
libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007ff6a25ae000)
libxcb-keysyms.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-keysyms.so.1 
(0x00007ff6a25a6000)
libxcb-randr.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-randr.so.0 (0x00007ff6a258e000)
libxcb-render-util.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render-util.so.0 
(0x00007ff6a2586000)
libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 
(0x00007ff6a2576000)
libxcb-shape.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shape.so.0 (0x00007ff6a256e000)
libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0x00007ff6a255e000)
libxcb-xfixes.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-xfixes.so.0 
(0x00007ff6a254e000)
libxcb-xinerama.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-xinerama.so.0 
(0x00007ff6a2546000)
libxcb-xkb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-xkb.so.1 (0x00007ff6a2526000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007ff6a24f6000)
libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007ff6a22e6000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007ff6a21a6000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff6a2056000)
libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0x00007ff6a2046000)
libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0x00007ff6a2026000)
libxkbcommon-x11.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon-x11.so.0 
(0x00007ff6a2016000)
libxkbcommon.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0 (0x00007ff6a1fce000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ff6a1e9e000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ff6a1e7e000)
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007ff6a1df6000)
libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007ff6a1dbe000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007ff6a1d9e000)
libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007ff6a1c96000)
libicui18n.so.66 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.66 (0x00007ff6a1996000)
libicuuc.so.66 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.66 (0x00007ff6a17ae000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff6a17a6000)
libpcre2-16.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-16.so.0 (0x00007ff6a171e000)
libdouble-conversion.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdouble-conversion.so.3 
(0x00007ff6a1706000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff6a3ac6000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007ff6a16d6000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007ff6a16c6000)
libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007ff6a166e000)
libxcb-util.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-util.so.1 (0x00007ff6a1466000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007ff6a145e000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007ff6a1456000)
libbsd.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007ff6a1436000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007ff6a13be000)
libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 
(0x00007ff6a1306000)
libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007ff6a12ce000)
libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007ff6a129e000)
libicudata.so.66 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.66 (0x00007ff69f7d6000)
libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007ff69f726000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007ff69f716000)
liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007ff69f6e6000)
liblz4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007ff69f6be000)
libgcrypt.so.20 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007ff69f59e000)
libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007ff69f576000)
(base) saltz@saltz:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms$
```

But I don't understand the "ldd libxcb.so" command .

What can I do now  ?  My OS is lubuntu 20.04    .

Comment: Your program try to find the directory `plugins` in the application directory but not found. You should copy the `plugins` from `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/` to your application dir then try again.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem with gambas3.

This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb".

ldd the file /usr/lib/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so
gaves missing libraries
`libxcb-render-util.so.0 => not found`
`libxcb-image.so.0 => not found`
`libxcb-icccm.so.4 => not found`

installing them fixes the problem.-